# JQuery multiple select in only one select

Tags: jquery, html

I have code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_browser" name="browser">
<option value="1">Chrome</option>
<option value="2">Mozilla Firefox</option>
</select>

<select id="id_type" name="type">
<option value="max">Max</option>
<option value="min">Min</option>
</select>
```

And I'm using this lib: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#methods

following the docs:

```
<script>
$('select').multipleSelect();
</script>
```

But this changes both field.
How can I use this lib to only 'id_browser select'?

Comment: The id attribute is unique, so pass that as your selector like `$('#id_browser').multipleSelect()`

Answer (score 1):

Selection inside of a jQuery item is the same as selecting using CSS.

So in this case, try something like

```
$('#id_browser select').multipleSelect();
```

This will select elements that have an `id` (specified by a `#`) of `id_browser`, then look for any elements inside the `#id_browser` element that are of the `select` type (specified with no special characters before `select`).

Here's a quick rundown of the types of CSS selectors:

```
#id
.class
type
```

Here's a great reference on CSS selectors from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

There's also an awesome page here that details complex selectors, which let you do almost anything with some advanced selector patterns: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/